# Image Browser (Open Dialog) using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Browse for an Image ?
How can i Browse for an Image using asp.net,
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a type of file manager/folder explorer.  If that is the case, there are a lot of options for you:

1. Great example of building your own from Matt Berseth - follow [this short tutorial](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/hwo_to_create_an_aspnet_ajax_s.html)
2. Download an open source control - http://www.izwebfilemanager.com/
3. Telerik has a great (but not free) file explorer control for sale - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

I'm guessing that the example from Matt Berseth is going to be the best option for you.  It's easy to implement and gives you great control.

Comment: As a side note, the Telerik RadFileExplorer is primarily used for browsing files on the SERVER. If you want to browse images on the CLIENT, you can use the browser provided FileUpload or a plug-in like Silverlight. Additional access is restricted for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

the FileUpload control will let you browse for and select a file.  How you use it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET doesn't have a *file dialog*. Since 2.0 however it provides a **[FileUpload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227677(VS.85).aspx)**. This renders as a standard html input type="file" with which you can upload images.